# In IBM Assistant how to Import intents through .csv file? I get an error

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

I am trying to import intents into IBM Assistant via a `.csv` file.

I have followed this official article from [IBM cloud](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/assistant?topic=assistant-intents#importing-intents-and-examples) but have not been successful in importing the intents. I have linked the excel sheet that I am trying to import I think it is in the correct format please correct me if I am wrong. I have also attached the screenshot of the error message that I get when I import intents. What am I doing wrong?. Please help.

[Link to the excel sheet](https://drive.google.com/file/d/13R2zUwC42VJSsVP8wlp8AnwUnKLzYs_k/view?usp=sharing)

[Error Message Screenshot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VySGx7r5N8snnhVMnIzwLzOVOPcqTHgT/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Please include the error message and more information into your question.

Answer (score 1):

So the error message says the formatting was acceptable, but no data was found. I tried opening the google sheet and i could see a preview, but was not authorized to access the file or something. In the preview I only saw one column, jsut the utterances, you also need the labels for them.

An easy way to see the formatting is to open the tool and go to the intents page and click export, then just mimic the format you get there

Answer (score 0):

In the CSV file provided, you'll see that the data that you've downloaded from Google Drive is quoted, like this:

"digital media course, About_Digital_Marketing_Course"

This is confusing the Watson intent system, which doesn't expect the quotes and doesn't know what to do with them. If you manually remove the quotes from the downloaded file and follow the upload instructions, the intents are created successfully:

[image: Watson Intent list]

Alternately, if you open your CSV file in Google Sheets and put each value in its own cell:

[image]

Then, export it to CSV, your export will be in the correct format:

I want to know about digital marketing course,About_Digital_Marketing_Course